allow composition of different objects conforming to pre-defined APIs through traits
How can we allow composition of different objects conforming to pre-defined APIs? One way I am trying to do is through using traits in trait but failed, my attempt
pub trait XAPI {
    fn new(y: YAPI) -> Self;
}

pub trait YAPI {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

pub struct X {
}

pub struct Y {
}

impl YAPI for Y{
    fn new() -> Self {
        Y {}
    }
}
impl XAPI for X{
    fn new(y: YAPI) -> Self {
        X {}
    }
}

Is that possible in Rust?
A concrete example in Java:
/* Online Java Compiler and Editor */
interface PocketAPI {}

class Pocket implements PocketAPI {}

interface JacketAPI {}

class Jacket implements JacketAPI {

  public Jacket(PocketAPI labelStore) {}
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("!!!");

    PocketAPI pocket = new Pocket();

    JacketAPI jacket = new Jacket(pocket);
  }
}


Consider either an associated type or trait objects depending on your precise requirements.  But also beware of trying to translate object-oriented paradigms into a non-object-oriented language.

A direct translation of your Java code will look more or less like the following (Playground):
pub trait PocketAPI {
    // Have pocket methods...
}

pub struct Pocket {}

impl Pocket {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

impl PocketAPI for Pocket {}

pub trait JacketAPI {
    // Have jacket methods...
}

pub struct Jacket {
    label_store: Box<dyn PocketAPI>,
}

impl Jacket {
    pub fn new(label_store: Box<dyn PocketAPI>) -> Self {
        Self { label_store }
    }
}

impl JacketAPI for Jacket {}

fn main() {
    println!("!!!");
    
    let pocket = Box::new(Pocket::new());
    
    let jacket: Box<dyn JacketAPI> = Box::new(Jacket::new(pocket));
}

However, you should know that a common beginner mistake in Rust is to try to apply OOP patterns on it. Rust is not object-oriented.
For example, in Rust we don't abstract unless we really have a need to. Contrary to Java, Rust doesn't have a List trait, nor a Map trait, even though it has two map implementations (HashMap and BTreeMap) and they do share some API surface. Also, in Rust, when we do abstract, we usually prefer static polymorphism (generics, no equivalent in Java) to dynamic polymorphism (dyn Trait, interfaces in Java), since it is more efficient and more flexible.
So in Rust, you will have only a Pocket and Jacket structs (no traits), and Jacket will contain a Pocket. If jackets may contain different type of pockets, we may use a trait (an alternative is an enum) - but we will probably be generic over it, and won't use dyn PocketAPI.

In Java, all objects are reference counted and live on the heap. It's therefore easy to get an interface reference to them.
In Rust, values by default live on the stack and cannot be cast into a trait object, as trait objects are unknown in size. They do not carry the information of how big the underlying object is.
This means you need to create a sized reference to the trait object; this can be done via two ways: a reference, or as a heap object (Box).
To stay close to the Java code, I'd use a Box:
pub trait XAPI {
    fn new(y: Box<dyn YAPI>) -> Self;
}

pub trait YAPI {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

pub struct X {}

pub struct Y {}

impl YAPI for Y {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Y {}
    }
}
impl XAPI for X {
    fn new(y: Box<dyn YAPI>) -> Self {
        X {}
    }
}

This gives us a new problem, however; it now says 'YAPI cannot be made into an object'. This is true, because the YAPI has a static function (that doesn't contain self), which removes its object safety.
The reason is somewhat complicated; the short version is that Rust can only determine which object is behind a trait reference if there actually is an object behind it. It then uses the self reference to decide which object it is (v-tables and stuff). But if you'd call new on a trait reference to YAPI, the compiler wouldn't know which function to call, because no self is connected to the call.
So if you remove new() from YAPI, it works as expected:
pub trait XAPI {
    fn new(y: Box<dyn YAPI>) -> Self;
}

pub trait YAPI {}

pub struct X {}

pub struct Y {}

impl Y {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Y {}
    }
}

impl YAPI for Y {}

impl XAPI for X {
    fn new(y: Box<dyn YAPI>) -> Self {
        X {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let y = Box::new(Y::new());
    let x = X::new(y);
}

